# Why Android BLE gatt callback method onCharacteristicChanged callback is called in lower rate in Wear OS device than on smartphone?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, android-ble

I develop an application designed for Wear OS devices that received data using BLE as Gatt client. I set the mtu size the maximum possible (517 bytes), and need to transfer some large amount of data - so I set the connection priority to `BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH` and from the logs I see the interval is set to 5ms.
I tested my app on Suunto 7 and also on Galaxy S9+ to see the BLE speed on both watch and smartphone and found out that when I get notifications from the Gatt server device I see that on Suunto 7 the onCharacteristicChanged callback is called around every 50ms, while on Galaxy S9+ the onCharacteristicChanged callback is called around every 5ms.
What might cause this difference and how can I make the onCharacteristicChanged callback to be called more often on Wear OS devices?
if it matters - the Gatt server device is also an android app I develop using `BluetoothGattServer` class and I send the data using notifications and not indications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's natural that you see the different delay in different device, because **Galaxy S9+** has `5.0, A2DP, LE` connection feature but **Suunto 7** is a small device with hardware limitations.

but if you want to fix this and get data in the same delay, you can add 45ms delay when **Galaxy S9+** connected.
First, you should get the device name in `onCharacteristicChanged callback`:

```
 if(gatt.getDevice().getName().equals("Galaxy S9+")){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       //run function
      }
    }, 45);
                    
  }

 else

   //run function
```

Comment: Thanks, got it, so there is probably no way I can increase the rate of the onCharacteristicChanged callback

Comment: By the way, I suppose you meant to delay if the device is smartphone because it has the higher rate.

Comment: oh yes, i edited the device name from Suunto 7 to Galaxy S9+... sorry about that